# You can see me if you get out more

Tags: riddle

> I contain some very important information.
>
> You likely display me all the time.
>
> But if you were asked to name my contents,
>
> You might not remember - perhaps -
>
> And you'd likely be in a bad spot and not be able to recall.
>
> Some places folks have two of me, some places folks have one.
>
> In some seedy places I often don't exist,
>
> But if you've got lots of money, you've got lots of the thing -
>
> The thing that needs ME stuck on its back.
>
> Getting me can be a pain; the lines are often long.
>
> (At least in the U.S., this should be a dead giveaway).
>
> All the same, though you see me every day,
>
> and you use me every day (indirectly)
>
> You probably don't think about me much
>
> at all.
>
> Who am I?

Comment: The title does have some relevance to the puzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer:

> License plate

I contain some very important information.

> The license details for the car

You likely display me all the time.

> It's fixed to the outside of the car whether you are using it or not.

But if you were asked to name my contents,

You might not remember - perhaps -

> People are a bit rubbish at remembering the license plate contents

And you'd likely be in a bad spot and not be able to recall.

Some places folks have two of me, some places folks have one.

> Some locales have them on the front as well as the rear.

In some seedy places I often don't exist,

> Dodgy people might remove plates or not have them in the first place

But if you've got lots of money, you've got lots of the thing -

The thing that needs ME stuck on its back.

> Cars, cars are *expensive*

Getting me can be a pain; the lines are often long.

(At least in the U.S., this should be a dead giveaway).

> The lines at the DMV are legendary

All the same, though you see me every day,

> You'll see them on your own car and others every day

and you use me every day (indirectly)

> By using the car you are using the license plate

You probably don't think about me much

at all.

Who am I?

Comment: Excellent! That's the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are an

> iphone!

The thing that needs ME stuck on its back

> I assume that is the Apple company logo on the back of the phone. The iphone is Apple's main income source (as far as I know) thus Apple needed their iphones to succeed.

Getting me can be a pain; the lines are often long.

> (At least in the U.S., this should be a dead giveaway)

I thought at first that you are a pc screen before those two lines.

Edit - my explanation:

> People hold their most important info, such as phone numbers, messages, photos and music on their smartphones. They are frequently holding them out at public, thus displaying them to everyone. People are usually interested in the specs of their phones only at purchase, and then gradually forget them. There are people with more than one phone, and under "seedy places" I assume poor countries or maybe off-grid farms there technology is not very popular/ available.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! Can you perhaps explains how your answer fits into the entire riddle?

Comment: Nice answer, but not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly outdated possibility, but...

> A car/road tax disc?

I contain some very important information.

> tax and ownership details

You likely display me all the time.

> displayed on the car

But if you were asked to name my contents,

You might not remember - perhaps -

And you'd likely be in a bad spot and not be able to recall.

> if you're pulled over for DUI, perhaps

Some places folks have two of me, some places folks have one.

> one or two cars

In some seedy places I often don't exist,

> people might not pay their tax in bad areas?

But if you've got lots of money, you've got lots of the thing -

The thing that needs ME stuck on its back.

> rich people could have multiple cars

Getting me can be a pain; the lines are often long.

(At least in the U.S., this should be a dead giveaway).

> do people in the US pay their tax in person?

All the same, though you see me every day,

and you use me every day (indirectly)

> when driving

You probably don't think about me much

at all.

> it's easy to forget unless it's time to pay

Who am I?

Comment: You're the closest, but that's not quite what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer!